# Trying to understand parenthesis balancing recursion in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion

I am new to Scala and functional programming. Disclaimer: yes, I am taking the Scala course on Coursera, and yes, this is part of the assignment. My only goal here is to get some help to understand how this solution works in order to develop my own solution and familiarize with functional programming.

I am stuck on this implementation of the recursive algorithm to check for parenthesis balancing. I simply don't get:

1. how the functions are structured
2. how the evaluation of the boolean expression occurs

```
def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
  def balanced(chars: List[Char], open: Int): Boolean = {
    if (chars.isEmpty) open == 0
    else
    if (chars.head == '(') balanced(chars.tail,open+1)
    else
    if (chars.head == ')') open>0 && balanced(chars.tail,open-1)
    else balanced(chars.tail,open)
  }
  balanced(chars,0)
}
```

My first doubt is the following. The inner function immediately starts by evaluating the boolean expression

```
if (chars.isEmpty) open == 0
```

My understanding (maybe wrong) is that here both expressions will be evaluated: `chars.isEmpty` and `open==0`.
However, the argument `open` doesn't seem to be yet defined anywhere. So why don't I get an error?
Second, I simply cannot get the line:

```
if (chars.head == '(') balanced(chars.tail,open+1)
```

Where will `balanced(chars.tail,open+1)` be evaluated and how?

Suppose I want to check whether `"("` has balanced parentheses.

```
if (chars.isEmpty) open == 0
```

Will return False, then

```
if (chars.head == '(') balanced(chars.tail,open+1)
```

The first expression will be TRUE, but the second one? "(" doesn't have a tail, and again I don't see how `open+1` works, since the integer `open` has not been defined anywhere. I am pretty confused.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that `open` is not defined? It's one of the function's parameters.

Comment: Yes but no value has been assigned to it. How can I know if open == 0 if open didn't take on any value so far?

Comment: By the same logic you could argue that you don't know what the value of `chars` is. A function's body is not evaluated until the function is called. And once that happens, you do know what the arguments are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misunderstanding one of the fundamental things - function definitions. Let's skip initially unimportant part of a program:

```
def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
  def balanced(chars: List[Char], open: Int): Boolean = { /* ... */ }
  balanced(chars,0)
}
```

Notice that the first line of `balance` function is just a function definition - its a local function. Once control flow hits the `balanced(chars, 0)` line it'll invoke this function - thus `open` variable would get initialized to `0`.

Hopefully that solves your "uninitialized variable" concerns. If you have any more questions just comment and I'll try to help you further.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful to solve the first important doubt I had. I still don't get how `if (chars.head == '(') balanced(chars.tail,open+1)` is evaluated. How can `balanced(chars.tail,open+1)` can be evaluated as a boolean? If I have, as mentioned, "(", the first expression will give True, but I don't see how to reduce the second. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Kauber Hm, not sure what you are missing there - balanced(chars.tail, open + 1) is just a function call - to a function that returns a boolean. It just works exactly the same as in any other programming language.

Comment: I think I got it know, I see what a function call is, but as said in the original post, I was really confused about the structure of the function. Thank you again

Comment: @Kauber Also note that `if (chars.head == '(') balanced(chars.tail,open+1)` is not evaluated by itself without the `else` part; this is like asking how is `2 +` evaluated.